# The app located in system/priv-app is not in the list of apps on the device, android13 and 14

Tags: android, android-source

I am having problems with my preload app on android 13 in the ** system/priv-app/** directory. It appears in the directory but at the time of flashing my unit it does not appear in the list of mobile apps.

Add the required permissions to the permissions whitelist located at **frameworks/base/data/etc/privapp-permissions-platform.xml**

Also add the app to the directory: **build/target/product/handheld_system.mk**

This is my Android.bp:

```
android_app_import {
 name: "Test",
 apk: "Test.apk",
 privileged: true,
 presigned: true,
 required: ["privapp-permissions-platform.xml"],
 dex_preopt: {
 enabled:false,},}
```

Does anyone know what I need to add?

I signed the apk, added it to the directories indicated in the official documentation, but it does not appear on the device when it boots.

Comment: A logcat would tell you what exactly PackageManager is doing here? By any chance did you miss the intent filter for action android.intent.action.MAIN along with  category android.intent.category.LAUNCHER in the AndroidManifest.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Does it show listed with package manager? `adb shell pm list packages`

Can you extract the APK from the device `system/priv-app/` or from the `out` folder in your AOSP source, and check if the signature is correct? `apksigner verify --print-certs MyApp.apk`

If the signature is broken you might need the preprocessed flag in your `Android.bp`, or in your Android.mk try this: `LOCAL_REPLACE_PREBUILT_APK_INSTALLED := $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(LOCAL_MODULE).apk`

Another thing is the ABI architecture of your APK and System Image do not match. You should check the ABI of both, e.g. if your image is `arm64-v8a` but your APK is `x86` it won't work.